# Why does log4net use object?

Tags: logging, indexing, log4net

Why doesthe signature of the ILog in log4net use object as arguments? eg:

```
    void Info(object message);
```

Why not just make it explicit and expect a string? Is there some sophisticated reflection capability behind the scenes to for example flatten out the message and convert it into a tabular structure? Or was it just a hindsight of the original creators?

This being an object seems to indicate the former, but I don't see any documentation about this.

Also I am planning to store the object in a database, can log4net automatically creates the entity for me so that the content of the message is easily indexed? IE. If I pass in an object with 3 properties, I want to see the 3 properties in seperate columns. Similarly with relationships I want to see relationship built on the fly.

Comment: So it can take anything that supports `ToString`, my guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. I would agree with Chris, that they used `object` so that you can pass anything. You would only need to worry about providing a useful `ToString()` implementation. Something similar is done in `string.Format()`.
2. Log4net does not support your "database scenario" directly, though it should be possible to implement it without too much expenditure. Basically you need to write your own appender and use the `MessageObject` property to retrieve the original MessageObject from the logging event. Then you could "easily" write to the database in any way you want.